# The winform textbox is not showing texts

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I am trying to read a byte array from MMF, convert it to a struct format and show the contents in a textbox(txtBoxShowMessage) and I can't get the contents displayed. It works with the MessageBox popups but not with the textbox.

I've been stuck on this for awhile. Can anyone help?

```
namespace CS_MemoryMappedFile_Read_윈폼1
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct Sequence
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)]
        public string name;

        public long minimum;

        public long maximum;

        public long current;
    }

    public partial class Form1: Form
    {
        private static Sequence ReadSequence(MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor)
        {
            Sequence seq;

            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Sequence));
            byte[] data1 = new byte[size];
            IntPtr p = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

            try
            {
                accessor.ReadArray<byte>(0, data1, 0, data1.Length);
                Marshal.Copy(data1, 0, p, size);
                seq = (Sequence) Marshal.PtrToStructure(p, typeof(Sequence));
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(p);
                p = IntPtr.Zero;
            }

            Form1 form = new Form1();

            form.txtBoxShowMessage.Text = "Name: " + seq.name + Environment.NewLine + "Minimum: " + seq.minimum + Environment.NewLine + "Maximum: " + seq.maximum + Environment.NewLine + "Current Value: " + seq.current;

            return seq;
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("test");
            MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor();

            ReadSequence(accessor);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `static` from `private static Sequence` and remove `form.` from `form.txtBoxShowMessage.Text`

Comment: @Chetan - Yep, that's it. Why not post as an answer?

Comment: @Chetan Thanks Chetan, it works now. Could you explain the logic behind though? I have no clue how it fixed the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: @HyunJoonJang - Since `ReadSequence` was `static` it could access the internals of any instance of `Form1`. You attempted to solve it by creating a new instance of `Form1`, but that wasn't the instance that you already had open. So by removing `static` then `ReadSequence` was able to access the internals of the current instance - hence you could update `txtBoxShowMessage.Text`.

Comment: @HyunJoonJang - Typo - "it could NOT access"

Comment: @Enigmativity Thank you so much for your help! Have a great day sir :)